# Float right on inline block makes element partially disappear

Tags: html, css

the button are wrapped in a inline-block, but I want to make it align to right. when I do float: right, part of it disappeared
html:

```
<div class="card answer" id="answer4" href="#answer4">
       <div class="btn-text-inline">
           React Generated HTML
       </div>     
</div>
```

css:

```
.btn-text-inline {display: inline-block;}
```

￼
before adding float:right

[image]

after float:right

[image]

Comment: Seems like "Add Comment" is in some fixed or absolute element that stretches across the parent, and the upvote/downvote buttons are beneath it. Did you try inspecting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advice to add a custom background-color css property to every single element on your website to actually be able to see how much space does each of the elements take. Maybe the buttons are hidden behind another element. In this case, probably behind 'add comment' element

If you know how to use developer tools in your browser, you can achieve the same by opening developer tools and hovering over the elements of interest.

Comment: ah interesting. i am gonna try it.

Comment: the add comment element is blocking the buttons. how can I move the btns to the top?

Comment: You have two approaches here: 1. you could change the &#39;add comment&#39; element not to be `display: inline`, because it&#39;s the default `display: block` of that div that makes it covering 100% of width. 2. Second option would be to position the element so that z-index property becomes available and increase the z-index to any positive value. For example :

    right_buttons {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
    }